# The parent content type specified by content type identifier 0x0101000728167CD9C94899925BA69C4AF6743E does not exist

Tags: 2010

After following this tutorial, using XML for definition of content types, it didnt work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460224%28v=office.14%29

Please help

The parent content type specified by content type identifier 0x0101000728167CD9C94899925BA69C4AF6743E does not exist

Comment: Just wondering if you ever found a solution to this - I'm in a similar spot with SP 2007 and can't figure out how to create the custom contentTypes

Answer (score 5):

You should specify INHERITS='TRUE' for parent contenttype

Comment: but where is the INHERITS? and what is parent contenttype?